Showing $(a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc)(x^3+y^3+z^3 -3xyz)=p^3+q^3+r^3 -3pqr$, if $(a+b+c)(x+y+z)=p+q+r$

If $(a+b+c)(x+y+z)=p+q+r$ then prove that
$$(a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc)(x^3+y^3+z^3 -3xyz)=p^3+q^3+r^3 -3pqr$$

I proceeded in the following way:
Suppose $A=a+b+c$ and $B= x+y+z$. Then $AB=p+q+r$. Now
$$\begin{align}
\text{L.H.S.} &= (a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc)(x^3+y^3+z^3 -3xyz) \tag1\\[4pt]
&= (a+b+c)\left((a+b+c)^3-3(ab-bc-ca)\right) \\ &\quad\cdot(x+y+z)\left((x+y+z)^3-3(xy-yz-zx)\right) \tag2\\[4pt]
&= (p+q+r)\left(A^3-3(ab-bc-ca)\right)\left(B^3-3(xy-yz-zx)\right) \tag3
\end{align}$$
Then I got the trouble.

A well known factorisation might help here: $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca) = \frac{1}{2} (a+b+c)\left[(a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 \right]$$

@Kraken I think it more likely that the full factorization
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a+\omega b+\omega^2c)(a+\omega^2 b+\omega c)$$ with $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ a complex third root of unity will play a role.

See this old thread. The answers by Anon in particular.

I don't think what you want to prove is  true:
Let $a=x=1,b=y=2,c=z=3$. Then $$(a^3+b^3+c^3 - 3abc)(x^3+y^3+z^3 -3xyz) = 18^2=324.$$
Let $p=10,q=12,r=14$, then $p+q+r=36=(a+b+c)(x+y+z)$ but
$$p^3+q^3+r^3 -3pqr=432$$

Well spotted. On the other hand, if you pick $p=10, q=r=13$, then the identity does hold. I will type an explanation shortly.

Warning: Not a full answer, but too long to be a comment. As Tri observed, this does not always hold.  My point is that we do get this identity if we specify $p,q,r$ a bit more carefully.
I'm fond of handling this three variable cubic polynomial as follows.
Consider the circulant matrix
$$
M(a,b,c)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} a& b& c\\ c&a&b\\ b&c&a\end{array}\right).
$$
It is well known that we get the cubic as the determinant
$$
F(a,b,c):=\det M(a,b,c)=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc.
$$
What the question reminds anyone well versed in linear algebra is the determinant product rule
$$
\det A \cdot \det X= \det AX.
$$
We obviously want $X=M(x,y,z)$. Furthermore, it is known that the product of two circulant matrices is itself circulant. Indeed,
$$
M(a,b,c) M(x,y,z)= M(a x + c y + b z, b x + a y + c z, c x + b y + a z).
$$
Putting all this together implies that
$$
F(a,b,c) F(x,y,z)=F(a x + c y + b z, b x + a y + c z, c x + b y + a z).
$$
In other words, the claim holds, if we, instead, specify
$$
\begin{cases}
p=ax+cy+bz,\\
q=bx+ay+cz,\\
r=cx+by+az.
\end{cases}
$$
The claim does hold more generally. For example, we can obviously permute $\{p,q,r\}$ any way we want. I'm afraid I cannot tell, what would be a sufficient and necessary condition for the identity to hold. The given constraint is satisfied with the above choice of $p,q,r$, but is not sufficient.

For the benefit of readers familiar with basic abstract algebra concepts: the algebra of $3\times 3$ circulant matrices is isomorphic to that of the ring $K[x]/\langle x^3-1\rangle$ where $K$ is the field we draw the constants from (most likely $K=\Bbb{R}$ or $K=\Bbb{C}$). The matrix $M(a,b,c)$ represents multiplication by the coset of $a+bx+cx^2$ w.r.t. the basis consisting of the cosets of $\{1,x,x^2\}$.

Checking for duplicates. This cubic recurs....

I do want to promote this old answer by Angina Seng who sadly is no longer with us.
